# Number of characters displayed for a SQL based report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to modify a report that shows health assessments using SQL. On the report, I would like to add a section for comments that were added to the health assessments. I was able to add the comment section, and with a suggestion provided here, I used SUBSTRING to limit the number of characters displayed on the report to 1000 as opposed to 8000. 
The issue I'm experiencing now is with limiting the number of characters displayed for the option 'Other' as shown below. I used SUBSTRING (ex: SUBSTRING(HltNutrition.Comment, 1, 1000)) for all of the assessments and have included the Nutrition assessment as an example (which is working correctly) along with the snippet of code featuring the 'Other' (Chronic) option (which is not working correctly).  I replaced 3 with 1 and although this did not produce an error, it did not have the intended effect for 'Other' as SUBSTRING([HealthAssessName].Comment, 1, 1000).
Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
  -- Nutrition
  INSERT INTO #ChronicCondition(IdApplicant, ExamDate, Condition, TreatmentNeeded, TreatmentReceived, Status, Comment)
    SELECT  #Enroll.IdApplicant,
            HltNutrition.ExamDate,
            'Nutrition',
            HltNutrition.TrtNeed,
            HltNutrition.TrtStatus,
            HltNutrition.Status,
            SUBSTRING (HltNutrition.Comment, 1, 1000)
    FROM    #Enroll
            JOIN HltNutrition ON HltNutrition.IdApplicant = #Enroll.IdApplicant
    WHERE   HltNutrition.Overweight = 1  

  -- Chronic
  INSERT INTO #ChronicCondition(IdApplicant, ExamDate, Condition, TreatmentNeeded, TreatmentReceived, Status, Comment)
    SELECT  #Enroll.IdApplicant,
            HltChronic.ExamDate,
            CASE ChronicCondition.Id
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Other' + ISNULL(' - ' + hltChronic.ConditionOther, '')
              ELSE ChronicCondition.Condition
            END,
            HltChronic.TrtNeed,
            HltChronic.TrtStatus,
            hltChronic.Status,
            SUBSTRING (HltChronic.Comment, 1, 1000)
    FROM    #Enroll 
            JOIN hltChronic ON hltChronic.idApplicant = #Enroll.idApplicant
            JOIN ChronicCondition ON ChronicCondition.Id = hltChronic.Condition
```

Comment: Why can't you use the SUBSTRING function on the "Other" option?

Comment: I believe I can use the SUBSTRING function, but I think I'm having trouble with which argument to assign. For all other assessments, I used 1 (ex: HltNutrition.Comment, 1, 1000), but I don't think this is the correct argument that should be used for 'Other'. If you look at the WHEN statement ( WHEN 3 THEN 'Other' + ISNULL(' - ' + hltChronic.ConditionOther, '')), I thought the argument would be 3, but that had no effect when I ran the report. So I think it may be the argument, not necessarily the function. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry, your response doesn't make much sense to me.   "Which argument to assign"?   Argument to what?   the reference to "3" is totally throwing me because it's not being used as as argument.   I suspect you may be misusing technical terms; maybe you should try to explain in plain english or with examples.

Comment: For the Chronic assessment I have SUBSTRING (HltChronic.Comment, 1, 1000). But in the SELECT statement I have this condition: 
            CASE ChronicCondition.Id
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Other' + ISNULL(' - ' + hltChronic.ConditionOther, '')
          I'm wondering if the 1 for SUBSTRING (HltChronic.Comment, 1, 1000) should be changed to SUBSTRING (HltChronic.Comment, 3, 1000) because of the WHEN statement or another number as I don't believe 1 or 3 correctly identifies what I'm trying to limit the characters for. I thought 3 due to the WHEN statement. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: No. read the documentation for Substring.  I don't think you understand what the second argument of the Substring function does.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the assistance, I walked through the concern with the senior developer and found that the SUBSTRING function was not the cause of the issue. The problem I was encountering was due to data entry that was used for testing the report. The code I added is actually correct and the problem has been resolved.

Thanks again for any assistance that was provided.